# understanding parameter expansion with positional parameter

Tags: bash

`x11-common` package installs a `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/20x11-common_process-args` script which is sourced in by `/etc/X11/Xsession`. This `20x11-common_process-args` script contains following if-statement:

```
has_option() {
  if [ "${OPTIONS#*
$1}" != "$OPTIONS" ]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
```

`OPTIONS` variable is a list of configuration options from a file separated by line-feeds(0a in ASCII). How to understand this if-statement? Literally, this parameter expansion part should modify the OPTIONS variable in a way that everything before the argument($1) is removed? This argument needs to match one of the configuration options. However, what is the general meaning of this if-statement?

Comment: Is there a newline like this in if condition?

Comment: @anubhava: Newlines are completely kosher in strings; the string happens to be in a test condition — no problem, though rather unorthodox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fragment of code:

```
xyz=gobbledegook
echo ${xyz#*de}
```

echoes "gook", so the `${OPTIONS#*$1}` notation deletes everything from the start of `$OPTIONS` up to *and including* the `$1`.

In the script, it is checking whether `$1` (the first argument to the function) is present in the list of options in `$OPTIONS`.  If the value is different, then the option is matched; otherwise, it isn't.  It's a fairly compact way of dealing with a lot of options all at once.

The newline in the test (well, strictly, it is in the string that is present in the test) is unorthodox but legitimate.

You can easily experiment for yourself, of course:

```
$ OPTIONS="-abc
> -def
> -ghi"
$ echo "${OPTIONS#*-abc}"

-def
-ghi
$ echo "${OPTIONS#*-def}"

-ghi
$ echo "${OPTIONS#*-ghi}"

$ echo "${OPTIONS#*-xyz}"
-abc
-def
-ghi
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the parameter expansion removes everything up to and including `$1` from the expansion. If `$1` is not present, then the expansion removes nothing, and the expansion is  identical to simply expanding `$OPTIONS` without modification. So, the `if` statement simply returns 0 if `OPTIONS` contains `$1` (that is, the two expansions are different), and returns 1 if it does not contain `$1` (that is, the two expansions are the same).

In broader terms, `has_option foo` succeeds if `foo` is present in `$OPTIONS`, and fails if `foo` is not.

Comment: It removes everything up to and including the appearance of `$1` in the string.